# Not able to see springboot response body in react-native

Tags: spring-boot, react-native

Hi I am trying to send back a response from spring boot to react-native for a controller call. I am not able to see the response body in it.

All i am able to capture is the status code 200 or 400 etc, i am attaching screenshot of the react-native chrome debugger.

I need to capture the message in react-native, Any help is greatly appreciated.

React-native code:

```
const signUpApi = (data) =>{
fetch('localhost:8080/v1/users',{ 
    method: 'POST',
     headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
     body :JSON.stringify(data),
    })
  .then((res) => apiResponseCheck(res))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e))
  .done()
}
```

SpringBoot code: I have tried two type of way to send the response

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@PostMapping(value="/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> addNewUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user) throws Exception {
    userServiceImplementation.addNewUser(user);
   return new ResponseEntity<>("User added successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}

@CrossOrigin("*")
@PostMapping(value="/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<UserControllerResponse> addNewUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user) throws Exception {
    userServiceImplementation.addNewUser(user);
    UserControllerResponse userControllerResponse=new UserControllerResponse(true,"User added successfully");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userControllerResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with Promise i missed one line in react-native

```
    const signUpApi = (data) =>{
    fetch(GlobalConstants.apiUrl+'v1/users',{ 
        method: 'POST',
         headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
         body :JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())               << this was missing
        .then((res) => apiResponseCheck(res))
        .catch((e) => console.log(e))
       .done()
}
```